# PInvokeStackImbalance was detected error

Tags: c#

I needed to port the following code from .c to c#.

```
typedef void (*CALLBACKERROR)(const char * ErrorString, int ErrorNum);
void WINAPI SetCallbackError (CALLBACKERROR CallbackError);
```

I have tried the following code: (using the DLL of the compiled c code)
defentions:

```
public delegate void MyCallback(String str, int a);
[DllImport(LibName, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern void SetCallbackError(MyCallback myCallback);

public void PrintCallbackError(String str, int a)
{
  Console.WriteLine("issue was detected");
}

Public void CheckConnection()
{
      SetCallbackError(PrintCallbackError);  -causes 1st exception
      OpenConnection(false);  - causes 2nd exception
…
}
```

1st exception:
[image]

2nd exception:
[image]

A solution that was come up to avoid the 2nd exception was to change the signature to not get any parameters at all – doesn’t make a lot of sense- but works…
defentions:

```
    public delegate void MyCallback();
public static void PrintCallBackError()
```

It is important to say that I can’t change the implementation of the c code.
I would appreciate any help and other coding solutions,

Thanks from advance –

Comment: Use CharSet.Ansi instead of unicode - native parameter is char*. Use Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate to pass managed method as native callback.

Comment: `CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl` What's `WINAPI` defined as...

Comment: " Alex Farber": 1. where do I call : Marshal::GetFunctionPointerForDelegate? 2. changing to ANSI didn't help the PInvoke exception :(  3. " ta.speot.is" I don't know what WINAPI is...do you think it is relevant?

Comment: Yes it is relevant.  It means CallingConvention.Stdcall.  All winapi functions are stdcall.